# Dynamic offset from last value found

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to reference a cell five rows up, after finding the last value of the column like so:

`=FILTER(quarterly2!B:B , ROW(quarterly2!B:B ) =MAX( FILTER( ROW(quarterly2!B:B ) , (ISNUMBER(quarterly2!B:B )))))`

How do I return the value that is fifth last from the bottom of this column B?

Answer (score 1):

OP has revisited but not responded to a request for clarification, so I'm guessing  inserting `-5` immediately after `FILTER( ROW(quarterly2!B:B )` was deemed adequate.